# Drupal Display "Master" Error in View

Tags: views

While I'm creating view displays for three of my content types, created first two and auto previews look fine. When I created the third one, the server kinda went down for a while. So I waited till it comes back online, I'm no longer able to auto preview any of the displays, and I'm getting the following error

- Display "Master" uses fields but there are none defined for it or all
  are excluded.
- Display "Page" uses fields but there are none defined
  for it or all are excluded.

Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried saving or canceling your changes after a page refresh?

Comment: it wouldn't let me to save. it shows the changes are saved temporarily or something like that, * still shows, but I have no trouble viewing the actual page of the display, just the auto preview won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you have at least one field listed under 'Fields.'  If you use a display type that requires fields without any being selected you will see the error noted in your question.

If it's bugging out, try to cancel your changes and refresh the page.  Add a field, save and see if the preview works again.